# Regex to identify "if" scenarios in java

Tags: regex

I've been trying to create a regex that identifies only the bold if below. Ive tried a few regex rules with no success.

**if** _if abcifabc guiif

I dont want to recognize the full if ( Condition ) { Statements }....

Comment: What's the criteria to identify bold if ?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex where you can use specific parsers, especially for complex languages such as Java. A quick google search will return a few of these parsers, and the languages itself contains tools to do so

Comment: @Aaron we don't know the task.  Of course parser is correct if you need a robust way to process code in production.  But the OP might be doing some quick hacking in an editor, or writing a quick script to run on a set of code files that follow a known standard.

Comment: @dan1111 you're right, but I still think this has to be said for two reasons : 1) OP might not have thought of the possibility to use a full-fledged parser and 2) other readers won't know the context either, and might think regex-based answers could apply to their problem. This is the same rant as "don't parse HTML with regex". Sure you can for a quick-and-dirty one-use script, but you shouldn't in the general case.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a language source for error's ? You'd have to do a lot of work, including strings, keywords, terminations, code blocks, recursions. If you found the if, what would it mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
(?:^|\s)if(?:\s)
```

[image: img]

Explanation of the regular expression:

```
NODE      EXPLANATION
------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:       group, but do not capture:
------------------------------------------------------------
    ^         the beginning of the line
------------------------------------------------------------
   |         OR
------------------------------------------------------------
    \s        whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
------------------------------------------------------------
  )         end of grouping
------------------------------------------------------------
  if        'if'
------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:       group, but do not capture:
------------------------------------------------------------
    \s        whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
------------------------------------------------------------
  )         end of grouping
```

Comment: Liked the layout of explanation.

Comment: Given how often the word `if` is likely to appear in comments and strings, it would be nice to at least see a disclaimer in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will match `if` preceded only by whitespace:

```
^\s*if\b
```

`^` - anchor to beginning of line.

`\s*` - match zero or more whitespace characters (including spaces and tabs).

`\b` - require a word boundary.  So it won't match `iffy`, etc.

A regex cannot perfectly identify a keyword in a programming language (as a completely correct solution requires fully parsing the language).  However, this should capture if statements pretty well in code that follows typical style.

Comment: right, I was in a "don't use regex when you should use parsers" rage and missed your disclaimer. I'm fine with this answer.

Comment: @Aaron, I don't get it. None of these regexes are safe for comments and similar (e. g. think of multiline comment strings). You can't cover that with regular expressions.

Comment: @steffen, it all depends on the task.  Sometimes you are doing some quick hacking and need a quick hacky solution.  Who doesn't use a regex in their text editor when coding, for example?  I made sure to state that only a parser can do this task perfectly.

Comment: @steffen I had missed the multiline comments, I removed my incorrect first comment. I'm still ok with the answer since it contains a disclaimer, the readers should be able to assess if that answer applies to their problem with all the relevant informations available.

Comment: @Aaron. Ok, added.

Answer (score 1):

`if` between two word boundaries:

```
/\bif\b/
```

But be careful as it matches all `if` words whereever they occur (e. g. comments).

Comment: Given how often the word `if` is likely to appear in comments and strings, it would be nice to at least see a disclaimer in this answer.

Comment: @dan1111 The question is quite vague, and so is the answer. There's no hint to a certain programming language. All we can assume is that the `if` is a keyword and for keywords you use word boundaries.